# Three different laravel projects with one authentication when database is same

Tags: laravel

I have 3 different laravel projects but their database is same. All users have access in all projects. So how it is possible that if a user login any one of the project he need not to login another projects. He will be auto login to another.

Comment: You mean when user1 login to project1, it must be auto login to project2 and project3?

Comment: yes @MONSTEEEER